# Polytopes that can be efficiently described and efficiently covered by cubes or simplices?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, packing-and-covering

1. Is there a bounded convex polytope $\mathcal P\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ with $m$ vertices, whose vertex vectors span $\mathbb R^n$ (so $m$ is $\Omega(n)$) and just $O(poly(\log n))$ half-plane inequalities to describe such that we can cover it in $O(poly(\log n))$ cubes of possibly unequal sizes?

By cover I mean every point in $\mathcal P$ is in some cube and every cube is totally inside $P$.

2. If we replace cube by a congruent simplices of different sizes will the estimate differ by much?

What if we drop congruences?

Is there general references?